# WatchKit - Get a touch location on a the screen

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

I am building an iPhone game with a watch extension. On the watch I would like the user to click on an image and I would like to know where on the image the user clicked. Is this possible with watchkit?

Update: In watchOS 3.0 this is no longer an issue. See answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With watchOS 3.0, you can now use `WKTapGestureRecognizer` combined with `locationInObject()` to get a touch location.

(still no `UITouchEvent` unfortunately).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the current version of WatchKit. The closest you could come to this is to detect that the user tapped an image/button. I suppose you could break the original image into smaller images/buttons and lay them out as a larger image, but I'm not sure how the performance would be.